# How do I upgrade python when I have already downloaded the latest version?

Tags: python, module

```
    ~$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

above is the code I get when I commend python3

And I think this is the reason I can't import modules even if I installed pip because the interpreter doesn't match.

How do I completely remove and change it to the latest version(3.10) of python?

Things I tried

1. I deleted all the versions of python on control pannel
2. I deleted 3.8 version on Ubuntu commend line using `sudo apt-get remove python3.5`
3. Reinstalling it

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First:

> I deleted 3.8 version on Ubuntu commend line using sudo apt-get remove
> ***python3.5*** # is it a typo here or on comand line?

Second:
have you tried:

```
sudo apt install python3.10.1
```

Comment: It says
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.10.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.10.1'
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get remove python3.5 but it stays the same

Comment: sorry then, that's all i got...

Comment: ah this is very difficult